# Determine ASCII Code of OlkTextBox KeyPress Event In Outlook VB Script Event Handler

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, ms-office, office-interop

I am building a custom Outlook form in Outlook, using

Developer > Design Outlook Form

I have enabled scripting in my Public Folders.

I have added a textbox to the form's "Message" page

I would like to capture, in a keypress event, the ASCII code of the relevant key, and limit the input in the textbox to numbers (0-9).

In the Script Editor: > Script > Object Browser, we can see that for the OlkTextBoxEvents.KeyPress member, the KeyPress variable is listed as a _IRecipientControl.

When we enter into the Object Help section, however, the KeyAscii variable is listed as long.

Neither appears to be appropriately declared, as we receive a "Expected ) at Line #" with both declarations.

If we simply specify KeyAscii as a variant parameter, we do not receive the error, however, that also means that I do not know how to access/manipulate the relevant key data.

How should the KeyAscii parameter be declared and used?

Comment: Is this VBA or VBScript? Or more likely VB.Net? They are not the same thing.

Comment: This is for a VBScript sub within a Custom Outlook form, but I tagged VBA to draw other Outlook folks, as I wasn't sure who would have a better handle on declaring the KeyAscii parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that controls in Custom Outlook form controls will only respond to _Click() events. As far as VB Script is concerned, these other events do not happen.